# SailsJs & Mocha : "policy.bind is not a function"

Tags: javascript, sails.js, mocha.js

My bootstrap.test.js file is as follows.

```js
var Sails = require('sails');

before(function (done) {
    process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';
    process.env.PORT = 9999;

    Sails.lift({
        models: {
            connection: 'localDiskDb',
            migrate: 'drop'
        }
    }, function (err, server) {
        sails = server;
        if (err) return done(err);

        sails.log.info('***** Starting tests... *****');
        console.log('\n');

        done(null, sails);
    });
});

after(function (done) {
    sails.lower(done);
});
```

A very simple modal test is available at tests/integration/controllers/AuthController.spec.js as follows.

```js
var assert = require('assert');

describe('PackagesModel', function() {

  describe('Sample Test1', function() {
    it('Sample test', function (done) {

      assert.equal(-1, [1,2,3].indexOf(4));
      done();


    });
  });

});
```

I try to run the mocha tests as follows.

```
node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha tests/bootstrap.test.js tests/integration/**/*.spec.js
```

This results in the following error.

```
   1) "before all" hook

  0 passing (1s)
  1 failing

  1)  "before all" hook:
     Uncaught TypeError: policy.bind is not a function
      at Object.policyHookDef.normalizePolicy (node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/policies/index.js:206:38)
      at normalize_each_policy (node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/policies/index.js:192:34)
      at arrayMap (node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:1556:25)
      at Function.map (node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:6886:14)
      at Object.policyHookDef.normalizePolicy (node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/policies/index.js:191:13)
      at node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/policies/index.js:172:59
      at node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3228:15
      at baseForOwn (node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:2199:14)
      at node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3198:18
      at Function.<anonymous> (node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3501:13)
      at node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/policies/index.js:167:11
      at node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3228:15
      at baseForOwn (node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:2199:14)
      at node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3198:18
      at Function.<anonymous> (node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3501:13)
      at Hook.policyHookDef.buildPolicyMap (node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/policies/index.js:150:9)
      at Hook.wrapper [as buildPolicyMap] (node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3250:19)
      at Hook.policyHookDef.bindPolicies (node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/policies/index.js:67:27)
      at Sails.wrapper (node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3250:19)
      at Sails.emitter.emit (node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/after.js:50:11)
      at Router.flush (node_modules/sails/lib/router/index.js:360:9)
      at Router.wrapper [as flush] (node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3250:19)
      at Router.load (node_modules/sails/lib/router/index.js:136:8)
      at Array.wrapper (node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3250:19)
      at listener (node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:600:42)
      at node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:542:17
      at _arrayEach (node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:85:13)
      at Immediate.taskComplete (node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:541:13)
```

Any ideas on what might lead to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might come across the same error in the future, the reason for the error was the usage of [sails-must](https://github.com/cludden/sails-must) middleware that I was using. In my policies.js file I had rules like the following.

```
MyController: {
    createStatement : ['isAuthenticated',must().have(runner).priviledge],
    getStatement :['isAuthenticated',must().have(driver).priviledge.or.have(clerk).priviledge]
  },
```

When the above lines were removed, tests ran. I know that this is not a complete answer with the cause of the error. But should be useful to someone else who comes across the same problem.

I switched to the approach mentioned in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288720/passing-parameters-to-sails-js-policies) to make my ACL logic.

Hope this helps!